# How to declare multiple arraylists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to declare multiple arraylists but i failed to do so. Is there a way to it?
here's my failed code:

```
List<Integer>[] table = new ArrayList<Integer>[]();
```

It seems no matter how and where do i put `'[]'`, it just doesn't work. any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Always specify the error you're receiving at the same time as the code that doesn't work. I assume this is failing at compile time? What's the error? (Note that that syntax is broken to start with as you're not specifying the size of the array, and you've got `()` as if you were calling a constructor, which you're not.)

Comment: `List<Integer> table = new ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: @karimmohsen: No, that creates a single list. The OP wants *multiple* lists.

Comment: Basically, the answer is that arrays and generics don't mix well in Java. You should consider using a `List<List<Integer>>` instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad , Create List of Lists  `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

Comment: @karimmohsen: No need for it to be declared as an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` - I'd just go with `List<List<Integer>>`, personally. Then you can add `ArrayList<Integer>` references to it - or other implementations.

Comment: thank both of you for your time and patience. @JonSkeet, sorry i didn't post the error and detailed information, will do next time, and i think your last post is what I'm looking for, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the size like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] table = new ArrayList[10];
```

Creates an array of ArrayList with capacity of 10.

Comment: it looks good, but i received 'uses unchecked or unsafe operations.' when compiling.

Comment: This is it, your array can't be sure that Lists that it holds will include just Integers. Yes this is unsafe, and actually using of arrays is unsafe and it's considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer>[] table = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) Array.newInstance(ArrayList.class, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> multiple = new ArrayList<String>(), myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

hope it helps.

Comment: It seems clear that the poster is trying to allocate an array of ArrayLists (despite the misleading title). This doesn't help with that.